# Type does not conform to protocol, but it does - migrating to Swift 3

Tags: facebook, protocols, swift3, xcode8, fbsdk

I'm migrating my app to Swift 3 and I encountered this problem. Been stuck for hours and nothing seems to help

[image]

Here's my code, it's visible that I'm complying with the protocol.

```
func loginButtonWillLogin(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!) -> Bool {
    return true;
}

func loginButtonDidLogOut(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!) {
}

func loginButton(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWith result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: Error!) {

    if (error != nil){

    } else if (result.isCancelled){

    } else {
        navigationController?.pushViewController(ContainerScreen(), animated: false);
    }
}
```

Anything that I can try to move forward? Thank you.

Comment: Sounds like you've defined a nested type `Error` in an extension of `UIViewController`, which is conflicting with the stdlib's `Error` protocol – is this true?

Comment: Nope, I don't have an extension of UIViewController in my project.

Comment: Huh, weird. If you CMD + click on `Error` in your `loginButton` method decleration, where does Xcode take you?

Comment: Apparently you are right. I have a coocapod that has a UIViewController extension. Good call!. How can I specify Error is the "Error" I need?

Comment: You could use `Swift.Error` in your method signature in order to disambiguate

Comment: @Hamish You just saved me hours of debugging......thank you....now go get yourself a scotch my good man

Answer (score 1):

Your `didCompleteWith` method has some problems, it seems that it has multiple parameters in the completion. But you have only two.

```
func loginButton(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWith completion : (button : FBSDKLoginButton, result : FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult, error : Error) -> () {

}
```

I dont have the proper syntax here, but I think that you got the concept. Your completion must have three parameters, you are missing the `FBSDKLoginButton`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I can't seem to find the docs with the proper syntax, and I'm currently unable to debug the project since I'm having issues with some cocoapods, but I'll comment as soon as I can try your solution.